# Number of $5$ coloring in a simple path.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $G$ be a simple path with $n$ vertices.WE color the vertices of the given path with five colors such that no two adjacent vertices are in same color.Suppose we color it with red,blue,white,green,balck.Find out the total number of combination to color the path if red and green color are not adjacent to each other.

My try:I am trying to solve it through a recursive relation. Let $T(n)$ denotes the total number of such combinations. If the last ball is neither red nor green then it could be with three colors.If it is Blue then we cann't take  previous of $n$ as Blue. So We subract those combination with has $n-1$th color Blue. So we have total $T(n-1)-T(n-2)$ choices for blue. So for all $3$ colors we have $3\{T(n-1)-T(n-2)\}$ choices. Now if the last ball is red. Then we must have previous of $nth$ as all colors except red,green. So we get $3T(n-2)$ choices. Similar argument holds if the last node is Green which gives $3T(n-2)$ choices.

So finally I get the recursive relation $T(n)=3\{T(n-1)-T(n-2)\}+3T(n-2)+3T(n-2) =>T(n)=3T(n-1)+3T(n-2).$ Am I going correct?If not then please mentation it and give a hint to solve this problem.Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $A(n)$ be the number of paths which end in red or green, and $B(n)$ be the number which end in one of the other three colors, then you can derive the following coupled recurrence:
$$
\begin{cases}
A(n) = 2B(n-1)\\
B(n) = 3A(n-1)+2B(n-1)
\end{cases}\tag{$n\ge 2$}
$$
Substituting $2B(n-2)$ for $A(n-1)$ in the second equation, you get an equation involving $B$ alone. 
$$
B(n)=3\cdot 2B(n-2)+2B(n-1)
\\\implies B(n)=2B(n-1)+6B(n-2)
$$
Similarly, substituting $\frac12 A(n)$ for $B(n-1)$ and $\frac12 A(n+1)$ for $B(n)$ in the second equation, you get
$$
\tfrac12 A(n+1)=3A(n-1)+2\cdot \tfrac12 A(n)
\\\implies A(n+1)=2A(n)+6A(n-1)
\\\implies A(n)=2A(n-1)+6A(n-2)
$$
This means that both $A(n)$ and $B(n)$ satisfy the same recurrence, which implies that $T(n)=A(n)+B(n)$ does as well.